# Adding two CSS3 animations?

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to apply a Minecraft-like style to a `div` element. The end result should look something like the "if not ok then return end" message:

[image: minecraft]

*Quick sidenote: For those of you who haven't played the game, a random line from a specific file is read and it's contents are displayed as the message of the day. It throbs in and out and grabs your attention.*

The text shadow, font, and throbbing animation has already been done. However, when I try to apply the second animation, it overrides the throbbing animation (meaning it does not throb, but is rotated)

My CSS is as follows:

```
#random-message {
    /* font/text stuff */
    animation:minecraft, minecraft-rotate 0.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:minecraft 0.5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

The animation `minecraft` applies a `transform: scale` effect, and `minecraft-rotate` applies a `transform: rotate` effect.

What would be the best way to implement a rotation effect without overriding my throbbing effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to have a rotation animation...you want to rotate the div. Simply add `transform: rotate(340deg);` line to the css block.

Comment: Still, the last animation/transformation overrides the first. If I have the animation set first, then the rotation, it would appear to be only rotated. It would be the opposite if the rotation was applied first.

Comment: In that case, simply rotate the container.

Comment: Oh. Hur dur. Kinda new to this, sorry :/

Comment: No problem mate, have fun with CSS! :D

Answer (score 0):

Any given element can have only one transform at any given time. Any attempt to set at the same time 2 transforms will result in one of them being overriden.

You can:

1) set two divs, one inside the other, and apply a different transform to the parent and to the child.

2) build the composite transform. In the case of an animation, that means creating composite transforms for each frame.